# HTML decode ASP.NET MVC string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got the following ASP.NET 4 MVC 3 code in a view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StateName, 
  new { data_provider = "typehead", data_items = "5", data_source = 
   "['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas','California']" })
```

The above is rendered on the page as:

```
<input data-items="5" data-provider="typehead" 
  data-source="[&#39;Alabama&#39;,&#39;Alaska&#39;,&#39;Arizona&#39;,&#39;Arkansas&#39;,&#39;California&#39;]" 
  id="StateName" name="StateName" type="text" value="" />
```

How do you display the data_source value unencoded? I'ved tried the `@Html.Raw(content)` as well as `@MvcHtmlString.Create(content)` with no luck.

Comment: Did my answer get you want you wanted? :)

Comment: Not quite, though I appreciate your help. We wrote a script block and created this `var names = @Html.Raw(['Alabama','Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California']") $('.typeahead-StateName').typeahead( {source:names} );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JQuery with the following line:

```
$("#PersonName").data("source")
```

This returns:

```
['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas','California']
```

Is this what you want?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jEWF3/1/